# Setting the resolution for an extracted YouTube video

Tags: c#, .net, youtube

I used the sample code from [this GitHub project](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor). When I change `info.Resolution == 360` to `480` or other, downloaded videos have no sound, only video. How can I correctly change the resolution of the video?

```
VideoInfo video = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == 360);
DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader(video, Path.Combine("D:/Downloads", video.Title + video.VideoExtension));
videoDownloader.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered switching to [libvideo](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo)? See the [comparison with YouTubeExtractor](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo#whats-the-difference-between-libvideo-and-youtubeextractor). Documentation for libvideo is [available in the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo/tree/master/docs).

Your problem can be solved (providing you switch) by reading [issue #31](https://github.com/jamesqo/libvideo/issues/31):

```
var videos = YouTube.Default.GetAllVideos("YOUR_URL");
var @480p = videos.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Resolution == 480);
```